# Bootstrap Hamburger icon animation in navbar-header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day everyone,

How to make menu Hamburger button animate to **X** in bootstrap [navbar-fixed-top](https://jsfiddle.net/8koahdrt/)?

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
              </ul>

            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

            </div>
 </nav>
```

I was trying to plug in all possible examples, but I am missing the point. Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for how to animate the transition, I think jQuery would be great for this.

```js
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function () {
  $(".open").toggle(500).siblings().toggle(500);
});
```

```css
.close {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

        <title>Test</title>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>

      <body>

        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
            
          
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <div class="open">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="close">
                  X
                </div>
              </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
              
            </div>
        </nav>

        


        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It is working @nfm! Much obliged! Is it possible to get animations with jQuery similar to these [examples](https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop) ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need create additional markup for close button

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <div class="burger> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="close">
               x
            </div>
          </button>
```

So, after that you need to update your css:

```
 .navbar-toggle .burger{
  display: none;
 }
 .navbar-toggle .close{
   display: block;
 }

 .navbar-toggle.collapsed .burger{
   display: block;
 }
 .navbar-toggle.collapsed .close{
   display: none;
 }
```

P.S. also you can easily add animations between default and **.collapsed** classes

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/8koahdrt/1/) example